# How to add MSBUILD 15 to windows registery

Tags: msbuild

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 and build tools of it it comes with MSBUILD 15 but in my regitery all i have is version 11 under tool version 4.0 which prevents me of building my app and return this error.

[image: one]

```
MSBuild v4.0 is not supported, aborting.
```

I've been reading solutions on internet and some suggested that we need to add it manually in system environment so I did it like this:

[image: two]

After some time I've found this official docs [here](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/releases). And I changed my environment to this `using Current`:

[image: three]

Yet I get the same error, so I was thinking if I add version 15 to registery manually it might solve the problem (not sure of it yet).

#### The question is:

1. How do I add msbuild 15 to registery manually?
2. Is there any other way rather than add it manually to solve the
   problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved / Not solved!

Apparently VS19 doesn't support cordova-windows so we are force to use VS17 :/

[Source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/issues/1001)